# Hiding Presented View Causes all views to hide Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I present a view here:

```
present(Djay.shared.PlayerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then I hide here:

```
Djay.shared.PlayerView.view.isHidden = true
```

Yet the view that presented this controller gets hidden too. How do I prevent this? I don't want to dismiss because I need the audio of the `Djay.shared.Playerview` to continue playing and I need to unhide this view at a later time to show its current state.

The view that presents is a view controller.

The view that is being presented is a view controller.

Comment: How about moving it off screen or changing it's z index to lie underneath the other views?

Comment: Let me see if this is viable.... @Jake I did Djay.shared.PlayerView.view.layer.zPosition = -1 and it didnt do anything :(

Comment: change the `modalPresentationStyle` of `Djay.shared.PlayerView ` to `.custom`

Comment: @deoKasuhal That worked , but now im back on the view that did the presenting and I cant interact with it

Comment: You need different approach to solve this problem instead of hiding the view. if you are not stopping the music on view appearance, you can dismiss the view and keep the viewController instance active till you need playback and whenever you need player control you can present on the screen with the current playing songs.

Comment: Thats a good idea.. I dont expect you to explain it all but can you please point me in the right direction on what to do ? @deoKasuhal

Comment: Create a singleton object of player view controller and present whenever you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by dismissing the view like normal , creating a singleton player for the music and Having the presented music player view dependent on that singleton object. Thank you to everyone that helped me out